# Heroku verify code in Google Authenticator app is gone

Tags: heroku

so i've *factory reset* my Android phone and **Google Authenticator** app is automatically uninstalled because of that.

The problem is when I'm install **Google Authenticator** app and login with the same Google account it's all gone including my FB, Heroku, etc for verifying code. I'm glad my FB 2-FA doesn't need **Google Auth** code.

The point is how to recover my Heroku account if I cannot login to verify my **authenticator** code? please help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the answer in [Heroku´s FAQ](https://help.heroku.com/7IDU8QZZ/what-should-i-do-if-i-m-locked-out-of-my-heroku-account).

Essentially, you need to contact support (support@heroku.com) and explain them your problem. They answer right away with a list of information you need to supply in order for them to verify your identity. This is what they required from me:

1. Names of 2 apps deployed on Heroku
2. The git SHA (hash commit id) of the most recent commits deployed to 2 separate apps on Heroku, including the date of the deployment
3. If your account is connected to GitHub, please provide: the name of the GitHub account the app or pipeline name of a connected GitHub repository the repository name
4. Date of Heroku account creation (this can be found in your Heroku
   account confirmation email)
5. Your billing zip/postal code
6. The invoice number, date, and amount for 2 of the last 6 months

I sent the info that I had and they gave me a 24h verification code. You log in with your email and password and on the next step, it will ask you to enter the verification code. Once you are logged in again, I recommend setting several MFA.